# How to replace all unicode characters except for Spanish ones?

Tags: regex, perl, unicode

I am trying to remove all Unicode characters from a file except for the Spanish characters.

Matching the different vowels has not been any issue and `áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ` are not replaced using the following regex (but all other Unicode appears to be replaced):

`perl -pe 's/[^áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ[:ascii:]]//g;' filename`

But when I add the inverted question mark ¿ or exclamation mark ¡ to the regex other Unicode characters are also being matched and excluded that I would like to be removed:

`perl -pe 's/[^áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ¡¿[:ascii:]]//g;' filename` does not replace the following (some are not printable):
`³ � �`
­

Am I missing something obvious here? I am also open to other ways of doing this on the terminal.

Comment: How is the input encoded?

Comment: Try `perl -CIOED -pe 's/[^áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ[:ascii:]]//g;' filename`

Comment: You need `use utf8;` or `-Mutf8` in order to include UTF-8 encoded characters directly in your Perl code (which is probably what your terminal is sending). In addition your input must be decoded and your output must be re-encoded, because files are always in some encoding. The encoding of the file is likely UTF-8 in which case `-CSD` (equivalent to `-CIOED` mentioned by @WiktorStribiżew) will do this encoding, but you should know this for sure.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @WiktorStribiżew and @Grinnz. Using `perl -CIOED -pe 's/[^áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ¡¿[:ascii:]]//g;' testing` removes all the unicode but the inverted question and exclamation marks yet doesn't retain the áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ characters like I'm expecting. I'm trying to retain áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ¡¿ and remove all other unicode (leaving just ascii) from an utf-8 input file.

Comment: Aside: Don't you want to keep ñ and Ñ, too?

Comment: You forgot ñ and ü, btw (I don't think Spanish uses umlauts with any other vowels but I'm rusty).

Comment: Your command does not inlcude `-Mutf8`. I mentioned that is required.

Comment: @Shawn and @Tom Blodget I did actually forget ñ and Ñ :) @Grinnz you are exactly right and my apologies for overlooking that. `perl -CIOED -Mutf8 -pe 's/[^áéíóúñÁÉÍÓÚÑ¡¿[:ascii:]]//g;' filename` works perfectly. I would be happy to accept your answer as the solution if you wanted to make your comment an answer.

Comment: @Shawn you are also right about missing the diéresis: ü

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a UTF8 encoded file and work with Unicode chars, thus, you need to pass specific set of options to let Perl know of that.

You should add `-Mutf8` to let Perl recognize the UTF8-encoded characters used directly in your Perl code.

Also, you need to pass `-CSD` (equivalent to `-CIOED`) in order to have your input decoded and output re-encoded. This value is encoding dependent, it will work for UTF8 encoding.

```
perl -CSD -Mutf8 -pe 's/[^áéíóúñüÁÉÍÓÚÑÜ¡¿[:ascii:]]//g;' filename
```

Do not forget about `Ü` and `ü`.

Comment: I notice Ñ and ñ also, obviously.

Comment: @tripleee Well, more can be added or removed, fortunately, that is the least trouble.